# Unable to read text file in Java using FileReader and BufferedReader

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader

i want read text file in java8, i am getting error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from FileReader to Reader". If I change Reader class to FileReader than I get error "The constructor BufferedReader(FileReader) is undefined"
My statements are

```
Reader fr = new FileReader("testfile.txt");
BufferedReader br =  new BufferedReader(fr);
```

Please suggest

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. My guess is that you've got a class called `FileReader`, so that the `FileReader` your code refers to isn't actually `java.io.FileReader`.

Comment: @JonSkeet more than a guess, I'd wager quite a bit that this is the only possible explanation for the two errors that the OP describes.

Comment: I have used import java.io.*;

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt: It's possible they have a `Reader` class instead of a `FileReader` class ;) (The conversion would be equally infeasible...)

Comment: `I have used import java.io.*`  Well, show us the code.  What you have there isn't enough.

Comment: @markspace My code is same as the one posted by Rishi Dua in Answer section, problem is I am getting the above mentioned two errors, if I try to make it work.

Comment: Then try this time without any import but using the class full path `java.io.Reader`, `java.io.FileReader`, `java.io.BufferedReader`. This should confirm our concern

Comment: @AxelH Well code is working, when I explicitly import all 3 classes. 
Any possible reasons why java.io.* didn't work?

Comment: Check my answer, with the final note to see what is the `FileReader` package when you use the import `io.*`.

Comment: @MDHUSENPAREET: I very, very much doubt that your complete code is *actually* the same as Rishi Dua posted. I *strongly* suspect there's also a `Reader` or `FileReader` class available other than those in `java.io`. It's unclear why you haven't posted a [mcve] despite the requests... (Compile it in a new project or directory, to make absolutely sure that nothing else is interfering.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To confirm that you are having a class with the name `FileReader`, just use the full class name in the code :

```
java.io.Reader fr = new java.io.FileReader("testfile.txt");
java.io.BufferedReader br =  new java.io.BufferedReader(fr);
```

This will assure that you use the specific class and not a `yourPackage.FileReader` class.

Then, since only `FileReader` seems to be problematic, you can clean it a bit like :

```
import java.io.*

...

Reader fr = new java.io.FileReader("testfile.txt");
BufferedReader br =  new BufferedReader(fr);
```

Only specifying the `FileReader` full name.

NOTE:

using [Class.GetPackage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getPackage--), you should find out which class you are using.

```
System.out.println(FileReader.class.getPackage());
```

## Explanation:

[JLS - 7.5. Import Declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5)

> The scope and shadowing of a type or member imported by these declarations is specified in [§6.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3) and [§6.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4).

[6.4.1. Shadowing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1)

> A package declaration never shadows any other declaration.
>
> A single-type-import declaration d in a compilation unit c of package p that imports a type named n shadows, throughout c, the declarations of:
>
> - any top level type named n declared in another compilation unit of p
> - any type named n imported by a type-import-on-demand declaration in c
> - any type named n imported by a static-import-on-demand declaration in c

## Example

```
A
A.Run
A.Test
B
B.Test
```

In A.Run.java

```
System.out.println(Test.class.getPackage());
```

Here is the output :

- Without import : Package A
- Without import `import B.*` : Package A
- Without import `import B.Test` : Package B

Comment: This is a reasonable test, I'd like to see the OP try this as well.

Comment: @MDHUSENPAREET Did some edit to explain why using an import * will not work.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. It has given me valuable insights on packages.

Comment: BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(System.getenv("OUTPUT_PATH")));   This throws a null pointer exception. Any pointers how to eliminate this error?                                  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:203)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:101)
 at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:63)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably importing something other than java.io.BufferedReader and java.io.Reader.

This works

```
package com.company;

import java.io.*;

public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            Reader fr = new FileReader("testfile.txt");
            BufferedReader br =  new BufferedReader(fr);
        }
}
```

Please check your imports;

Comment: No, that code wouldn't work: the FileReader constructor can throw an IOException which you're neither declaring nor catching, and you haven't declared a class. If you're going to provide an example you claim compiles, please make sure it actually does.

Comment: I get error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from FileReader to Reader"

Comment: The above code does compile for me (I didn't test it).  The OP should show us his code because his question doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: @RishiDua I still get error cannot convert from FileReader to Reader.
Have copied your code asis.

Comment: Do you have a class called Reader or FileReader in your package directory? That seems to be the only possible thing to me now.

Comment: Also, if you've been making many small projects as part of a series of programs (say homework assignments from a class) it's possible to have an old class named `FileReader` still present from a previous piece of code.  Might make sense to start a new project, and make sure you've got only the basic Java runtime at the start.